# In Microsoft Network Monitor, how can I capture a single payload?

Tags: windows, payload, netmon

In Microsoft Network Monitor, I have a HTTP payload I want to capture that is not chunked, the data received is only 21K. How can I capture this data and save it to a file?

EDIT: Also is it possible to drop all non-matched packets?
EDIT: Why the downvote? There were already questions on this site about netmon, so I thought it was okay.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Microsoft Network Monitor did not meet my needs. Instead I used wireshark.

Make sure the follow TCP option is set. I simply clicked the frame where the HTTP request/response was located, and clicked "Follow TCP", from there a window appears showing the collated chunks.